# running shell script in cloud SDK

Tags: gsutil, google-cloud-shell

Getting below error when i tried to run shell script with gsutil in cloud SDK

[image]

Comment: Can you share the command you ran? `gsutil` doesn't support direct execution shell scripts, but you could pipe it to a shell.

Comment: gsutil cat gs://your-bucket/your-script.sh | sh

Comment: I was able to run the same command in my Cloud Shell with a simple Hello World sh script. https://i.stack.imgur.com/X10q5.png Your error might be something in your shell script. What does it do?